# Cross Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource(Access Control Allow Origin doens not match '(null)')

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

Angular 2.0 application is trying to interact with Rest Server, getting below CORS issue
[image]

Below is my CORSFilter implementation

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", request.getMethod());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
```

Surprisingly same war file if i deploy in local(client is on 3000 port and server is on 8080) it is working fine, in local am not getting **access-control-allow-credentials** and **access-control-expose-headers**, where as in if we deploy it in Server am getting those headers and CORS issue is coming.

UPDATE: we deployed in different server which is http:// application is working fine, where as it is throwing error on https://

Comment: `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")` 
 Is that same in server ?

Comment: http://local host:3000 is where my client app got deployed, server is on https://test.com

Comment: Did you solved ? I am facing same problem.

Comment: Not yet @Thirumal.!

Comment: It worked for me also added  the answered.have a look@RameshKotha

Answer (score 0):

Modify Access-Control-Allow-Origin

```
 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
```

And, Permit all HttpMethod.OPTIONS request.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            //.and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
            .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint)

            .and().addFilter(basicAuthenticationFilter(super.authenticationManagerBean()));
}
```

@ramesh-kotha,  For more information have a look at [CORS OPTION and GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Thanks, will check and let you know.!